# Javascript using document.createElement() and node .appendChild() with <table>

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm trying to figure out a way to join the rows and table cells together using document.createElement() and node.appendChild() but I am a bit new to these commands.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html onmousedown='event.preventDefault();'>
<head>
<title> Boxes </title>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<style>

  table {
   border-spacing: 6px;
   border: 1px rgb(#CCC);
   margin-top: .5in;
   margin-left: 1in;
   }

  td {
   width: 40px; height: 40px; 
   border: 1px solid black;
   cursor: pointer;
   }

 </style>
 <script>

function colorize(el) {
  var
    r = ('0'+(Math.random()*255|0).toString(16)).slice(-2),
    g = ('0'+(Math.random()*255|0).toString(16)).slice(-2),
    b = ('0'+(Math.random()*255|0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
    el.style.backgroundColor = '#' +r+g+b;
    }
  </script>
```

Fill in the table body tbody element identified with the id 'tb', making it a 16x16 table using document "create element" and "node append child" methods to create the rows and table cells and join them together.

I know it will need something like "document body append Child(k)" along with a var to reflect the proper creating like  "var k = document create element"

```
</head>
<body onload='maketable();'>
<table>
<tbody id='tb'>

<script type="text/javascript">


var row = 16;
var cols = 16;

 for(var r=0;r<row;r++){
  document.write("</tr>");

 for(var c=0;c<cols;c++){
  document.write("<td onMouseEnter='colorize(this);'></td>"); 
  }
  document.write("</tr>");
  }

</script>

</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example below with appendChild.See the comments as you go through the code

```js
function colorize(el) {
  r = ('0' + (Math.random() * 255 | 0).toString(16)).slice(-2),
    g = ('0' + (Math.random() * 255 | 0).toString(16)).slice(-2),
    b = ('0' + (Math.random() * 255 | 0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
  el.target.style.backgroundColor = '#' + r + g + b;
}
var row = 16;
var cols = 16;
// create a table element first
var table = document.createElement("table");
table.id = "tb"

for (var r = 0; r < row; r++) {
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  table.appendChild(row);
  for (var c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
    var cell = document.createElement("td");
    //add A mouse enter event to each cell
    cell.addEventListener('mouseenter', colorize)
    cell.innerHTML = "cell";
    //append the cell object created to the row in focus
    row.appendChild(cell)
  }
}
//finally append the table to the body 
document.body.appendChild(table);
```

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 6px;
  border: 1px rgb(#CCC);
  margin-top: .5in;
  margin-left: 1in;
}

td {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: This is great! I made some corrections and noticed that the count is off on column and rows. It seems to be ignoring the 16x16 i set. Is there something I'm overlooking?

Comment: can you create a fiddle or pen with the codes inside?

Comment: yes I have ran the code in my own IDE. I also fixed some of the missing ; I'm just unsure why there's only one row.